# Bad certificate in call out

Tags: callout, certificates

I use the certificate provided to me. During callout, I get this message in the developer console.
[image]

Is this a bug on the side of SF or an external system? How can I verify the correctness of the application of this certificate from the SF and from the external system?
Do we have clear requirements for this certificate?

What's the API that you try to reach?
This is an external system and I try to get data from the endpoint

Is it a custom app or an out-of-the-box one? - out-of-the-box

Do you know their policies on certificates? - no

Is it you who sets the cert up on the other side? - no and they try to provide me with a lot of variants

If it's your custom solution, could you please share some code of your configuration? Ideally for both Apex and the external service.
I'm just trying to make a callout

```
String xx = 'https://test.com.eu:8201/test/Rent';

System.debug('APIHandler');
HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest();
r.setHeader('user', '8888');
r.setMethod('GET');
Http requestClient = new Http();
r.setEndpoint(xx);
r.setTimeout(120000);
r.setClientCertificateName('**certificate**');
HttpResponse response = requestClient.send(request);

System.debug('response ' + response);
System.debug('response.getBody() ' + response.getBody());
```

Comment: What's the API that you try to reach? Is it a custom app or an out-of-the-box one? Do you know their policies on certificates? Is it you who sets the cert up on the other side? If it's your custom solution, could you please share some code of your configuration? Ideally for both Apex and the external service.

Comment: @PrzemysławDługoszewski-Tamoń thank you for your answer - I updated my question

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. So what's with `r.setClientCertificateName('**certificate**');`? Did you make it on purpose to hide the name of the cert, the `**certificate**` is an actual name of it in your org or it's the copy-paste from some help portal? I'm not sure whether you can use asterisks in the `Unique Name` field - have you followed steps from [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_http.htm)?

Comment: If you generated the Self-Signed Certificate in your Salesforce org, you should pass its `Unique Name` in your Apex code in the `setClientCertificateName` method. Also, if you want it to work with the external service, I'd say that it's probably necessary to upload it there as well.

Comment: *tiny remark - I use ** certificate ** for bold style of the certificate word

Comment: Yes it uploaded on customer side as well

Comment: they try to make chains of cert in on jks - and include certificate signed by a certificate authority (CA)

Comment: Could you provide some docs to this external system? Especially these connected with the authentication?

Comment: they try to include certificate signed by a certificate authority (CA) in this JKS

Comment: Can you download the certificate and check in [SSL Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html) if the certificate might be corrupted? Also,make sure your certificate is signed by CA's listed in https://login.salesforce.com/cacerts.jsp

Comment: @Swetha Calling out from Apex isn't subject to this restriction, no?